# Lookup data to enter in forms and streamline process with FusionTables

Tags: google-sheets, google-fusion-tables, google-forms

I have a form with 4 questions InGameName, PointOfInterest, Region and Location.
Region and Location are possible lookup candidates and simply to large to put in a List Question.
To reduce clutter it would be neat if people only would neat to fill in their name and the name of POI if it's already visible on the  GFusion table map.

I have a 2nd GSheet with the possible answers where data can be looked up.

I would like to put this formula in row 1 and apply it to the whole column. visible
Furthermore this formula should not generate a error code when there isn't any data..

Kind Regards
Guy

Answer (score 0):

What I found to work was..

First you need a Master GSheet with all answers...
Then you can import all these answers in the Form Answer repository which isn't the same as you "Answer GSheet" look [Here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/importing-responses-into-a-google-docs-form-spreadsheet)

Then due to recent changes in Gsheet you need to connect the "Response Sheet from the form" with your "Master Sheet" in order to get the importrange to work.

`=IMPORTRANGE("<URL Master GSHEET>";"Sheet1!A2:C"`)

So this formula needs to be in the "Response Sheet"
you'll get a #REF! error

[image]

Hover over the error and click Allow access button.

Now you can use the following formula:

```
={"Location";IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(vlookup(B2:B;IMPORTRANGE("<Master GSheet URL>";"Sheet1!A2:C");3;false)))}
```

Location will be the name of the column from the second row you'll get the formula outcome

IFERROR if there's an error with the formula you get a blank line or if you put this <;"Error Msg")}> instead of <)}> at the end of the formula you get your Error Msg

ARRAYFORMULA(vlookup(B2:B will expand the formula to the whole column B

Vlookup search for every value in B column from B2 in the Master Gsheet on Sheet1! in column A2 till C If found return value from tirth column. False is needed to only on a exact match get a value.

This formula is ideal to streamline answers with GFusion Tables
-People don't have to fill in a lot.
-only answers filled in are copied to the GFusion Sheet no blank lines
-People can overide and Fill in new map data

For reference [here](https://github.com/Forsskieken/google_forms_to_fusion_tables/edit/master/script%20for%20Google%20forms.txt) you'll find GSheet ---> GFusion Table sync script that is also triggered with a form admission all credist to Lee Clontz.